# LaTeX techniques and templates for writing a book

Tags: listings, book-design, sweave, r, books

I am about to write a couple of books using LaTeX. I am fairly used to producing small LaTeX articles using Sweave and R, but I have never written a book using LaTeX and I am not conversant with the LaTeX practices standard for writing books.

Also, though I have a few ideas about how to structure such a big document, not having written a book in LaTeX myself, I don't know what works and what doesn't in the long run.

The books I am writing are:

- A book with a lot of charts and code (in R), and a few tables. I'll be using Sweave with this.
- A book with a lot of text and a few images. I'll be quoting passages and quite a few poems. An entire section/chapter could consist of poetry.

Here are my questions (answers with examples/references will be appreciated):

1. What techniques/best-practices should I follow in writing the books using LaTeX? What are the packages that are typically helpful?
2. What are the packages in LaTeX that I could/should use for typesetting poetry?
3. Sweave is nice enough for including R code, but I would like something that looks more professional. I have seen and used `listings`, and though I still don't have a set of options which looks fancy enough, I am guessing `listings` will do with enough tweaking. Am I missing out on anything? Should I be using `listings` with any other package? Do you have nice `listings` templates to share?
4. Any nice templates for writing books? Or helpful online resources specific to writing books with LaTeX?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This site works best if you ask one question at the time.

Comment: IMHO two great resources to begin with: [A Few Notes on Book Design](http://texdoc.net/pkg/memdesign) and [The Memoir Class
for Configurable Typesetting](http://texdoc.net/pkg/memoir), both from `memoir`'s author Peter Wilson (manual maintained by Lars Madsen). `:)`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a general introduction to book design using LaTeX, do check out [*A Few Notes on Book Design*](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/memdesign/memdesign.pdf) by Peter Wilson. Obviously, there is no single "correct" answer as to how a book ought to be designed. If you have considerable freedom in selecting a design, as seems to be implied by your question, you could start by simply taking a close look at the layouts of some books -- whether or not they are in the same field as the book you intend to publish -- and decide whivh parts of the overall design of these books you like (or dislike).

Among the criteria should be

- size and proportions of page -- and of text block within a page?
- are there (wide) margins containing supplemental notes, callouts, etc.?
- use of running headers?
- layout of sectioning headers (chapters, sections, subsections, etc)
- font and font sizes?
- use of color (including "bold", i.e., more black than normal text font)?
- use of boxes and other visually-appealing techniques?
- quality of paper (shiny or matte; smooth or rough to touch)?
- if the book will be available in electronic format: any hyper-linking of materials?

And so on... Have fun!

Answer (score 8):

Since you mentioned R, I would recommend you to use the `knitr` package instead of Sweave. You can go to the package website to know more about it: http://yihui.name/knitr It is much more flexible and customizable than Sweave. For example, you only need to call `render_listings()` in order to switch to the `listings` package (e.g. http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/listings/). <del>Recently I also started thinking on writing a book: https://github.com/yihui/knitr-book The basic sketch is there, and I'm writing with markdown instead of LaTeX since the former is much easier to write; I can convert markdown files to LaTeX later with `pandoc` if I want.</del> I have finished [the knitr book](http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781482203530) using `knitr` and LyX.

Comment: Hey, I have started using knitr. Thanks for a job well done.

Comment: @Soumendra good -- now I have finished a book based on knitr :)

Comment: Almost an year down the line, I have made a complete switch to knitr, and I don't know how I could ever live without it.

Answer (score 2):

I apologize in advance for this being not much of an answer--but as N.N. mentioned in his comment, you'll get much better responses if you ask each of your questions separately.

1. and 4.  I'm also a beginner at LaTeX, but I've been using the [`memoir` class](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) to write a book, and it's been incredibly helpful.  It has built-in support for chapter headings, page headers and footers, indices, etc.
2. You might find [this article](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/verse/verse.pdf) helpful.